# Issues when parsing Json response in Android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

Having the following code, within some more code:

```
@Override
public void handleFailureMessage(Throwable e, String responseBody) {

    Log.d("handleFailureMessage", "e: " + e);
    Log.d("handleFailureMessage", "errorResponse: " + responseBody);

    System.out.println(responseBody);

    JSONObject error = responseBody.getJSONObject("error");
    Log.d("error", error.toString());

    String message = error.getString("message");
    Log.d("message", message);

    dialog("error", message);
}
```

The error returned is something like the following:

```
{"error":{"type":"incomplete_data","message":"Key either not set, or invalid"}}
```

I'm just trying to reach the "message" part, and output the text

So I know `responseBody` is a string, but how would I convert it to a `JSONObject` so I can access `error` ?

Comment: Since when is there a `.get` method on a String? does `responseBody.get(0);` really compile?

Comment: I don't get it, what does that have to do with it?

Comment: Yes, but `responseBody` is declared as a `String`, not a JSONObject. You can't use methods of a JSONObject on a String.

Comment: I would much appreciate the explanation of the downvote

Comment: "This question does not show any researcheffort, it is unclear or not useful". My reasons for downvoting: 1) You tried to use .getJSONObject on a String, you could have found out how to properly create a JSONObject from a String. 2) "The error returned" sounds like you actually do get a result from the code above - which doesn't even compile. 3) It's not clear from your question that you actually get a compile error.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg before I ever ask something, I spend time searching for a way to fix it. It compiled, but it didn't output the desired message. What do you want, since my first day at full speed with Java and Android its self. I'm not excusing my self, but just explaining my point of view. I turned to SO, because I had no other resource to get help but you guys

Comment: You wanted the explanation of the downvote, I gave it to you. responseBody.getJSONObject can't compile as long as responseBody is a String or did you make a typo in your question? Googling for "string to jsonobject java" gave me very clear results.

Comment: Trust me, I search for about 45 minutes every possible combination that I could think of, just not to make "stupid" questions. Newbie mistake, sorry for wasting your time

Comment: The question itself was not stupid, just not very well formulated.

Comment: Thank you @SimonAndréForsberg I will try harder next time to better formulate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get `message` value from current json string as:

```
try {
    JSONObject error =new JSONObject(responseBody);
    JSONObject errorobj = error.getJSONObject("error");  // get error JSONObject
     // get  message from error JSONObject
    String message = errorobj.getString("message");
    Log.d("error", message);

} catch (JSONException e) {
      Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error :" + e.getMessage());
  }
```

because you need to create `JSONObject` from json string to get value from JSONObject

Comment: @w0rldart : by default if you are using Eclipse then it say to put json related code inside try/catch block .

Comment: @w0rldart in case the passed string is not correctly JSON-formatted, you will need to catch the exception. Surround it with a try-catch statement. If you don't know what that is, look it up.

Comment: @w0rldart : plz add latest code in your question if u are getting any error

Comment: I don't know what was it, but after a couple of runs... it started showing the proper message